# popup window at the bottom of page - javascript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Need the  popup window to show at the bottom of browser  should hide  after 5 seconds & display again.   Problem is I need to scroll till the bottom of the browser window to see the popup window.  Have used fixed and position bottom.    Want the popup to display at the bottom of viewport.  Want to do it in javascript  Have the below css.

**css**

```
.productPurchasePopup {
    width: 300px;
    height:100px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 50000;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    left:20px;

}

.productPurchasePopupContainer {
    width:100%;
    height:65px;
    line-height:14px;
}

 <div className={classes.productPurchasePopup}>
 
 
            <div className={classes.productPurchasePopupContainer}>    
              <div className={classes.productPurchaseImageWrapper}>
                  <a href={itemDetails.product_url_path} >
                     <img width='120' height='70' border='0' src={itemDetails.product_image_url} />
                   </a>
               </div>
               <div className={classes.productPurchaseText}> 
                   <span className={classes.salesPopupTitle}> Someone in  {" " + locArr[0]+", "+locArr[1]+" " } just bought for</span> 
                   <span class="sales-popup-price"> Only { " " +itemDetails.product_price}!</span>
              </div>
            </div>  
           

          </div>
```

Comment: did you tried `absolute` for **position** ?

Comment: fixed is more preferable here than `absolute` so use `position: fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is set the div with property `position: fixed` in your css,  which you want to fix in the bottom of your screen and not page.
Adjust what place you want it to be using  `top` and `right` properties.

Also, Give it a class which you will change using javascript in your code for the purpose of hiding that particular `<div>`
`<div className="no-display">div fixed at bottom</div>`

Now Comes in javacript, where you can use a setTimeout function to for that particular function to add **no-display** className on every time the timer goes out.

Resourse for setTimeout : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
Note: You site will be in process every time as you will be using setTimeout in in loops.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Already have position:fixed but its not working.   Need the popup to be at the bottom of screen but its appearing at the bottom of page.

Comment: then please use https://codesandbox.io/s/ to share your code with us and we can look after the issue properly. 
apart from that. I can  provide a reference for the css fixed property.
resource: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/#fixed